# UNION postgres - Run according to boolean

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that has one 'UNION' of postgres.

I use it with a filter.

I need to run the 'UNION', sometimes yes and sometimes not.

Can I use a boolean parameter to annul this 'UNION', according to my needs?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 sales2007q1
UNION  // With a boolean say if I want or not, execute this union
 SELECT *
 FROM
sales2007q2;
```

Comment: Can the boolean condition be drawn from one or more of the tables involved in the union?

Comment: No. I will pass it as a parameter to the query. It is a query that I have integrated into a JPA NativeQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add a `WHERE` clause to the second half of the union query which uses the parameter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales2007q1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM sales2007q2
WHERE ?
```

Where you see the `?` placeholder you may bind a boolean value from your Java code.  For example, if the parameter were false, then the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales2007q1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM sales2007q2
WHERE FALSE;
```

In this case, the second half of the union would just return an empty result set, since the `WHERE` condition would fail for every record.